# Why is a unique Sylow p-subgroup normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

I need to prove that a group $G$ with $|G| = pq$, where $p$, $q$ are primes, cannot be simple. I have already reduced this problem to showing that a unique Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal. The answers i have found so far are something along the line of "the Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal because all $p$-Sylow subgroups are conjugate to each other" which means diddly-squat to me. I need help understanding that last part.

Comment: I think it's because if it's the only subgroup of that order, then it's characteristic (every automorphism fixes that group), and all characteristic subgroups are normal :)

Comment: $N$ is normal in $G$ if and only if $gNg^{-1}=N$ for all $g \in G$.  This is exactly saying that $N$ always conjugates to itself.  If there is only one such group and conjugation preserves order, guess what?

Comment: You don't need the fact that all Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate. It's simpler than that. If $H$ is the unique Sylow $p$-subgroup, then it is the **only** subgroup of that order. Any automorphism (including conjugation) of $G$ must map $H$ to another subgroup of the same order. Since $H$ is the only such subgroup, $H$ must be mapped to itself. In particular, the conjugate of $H$ is itself, so $H$ is normal.

Comment: I think @Bungo put it better than I did :)

Comment: @Foobanana Your remark is quite correct, I just put a bit more detail :-)

Comment: @Bungo The problem is that my textbook never states that conjugation preserves order, and my intuition isn't strong enough to see why that is the case

Comment: @mikkelmk The reason for that is quite simple. If $H$ is any subset (not even necessarily a subgroup) of $G$, then $gH$ has the same order as $H$, since left-multiplication by $g$ is an invertible operation (to undo it, just left-multiply by $g^{-1}$). For the same reason, $gHg^{-1}$ has the same order as $gH$, and thus the same order as $H$.

Answer (score 29):

Suppose that $H$ is the unique $p$-Sylow subgroup, for any $g\in G, gHg^{-1}$ is also a $p$-Sylow subgroup since it has the same cardinal than $H$, since $H$ is the unique $p$-Sylow subgroup, $gHg^{-1}=H$ so for every $h\in H, ghg^{-1}\in H$ and $H$ is normal.